# Declaring more than one LANG in html

Tags: html

I am starting a project and I want to know if I can declare more than 1 lang in html??

The idea is to make a landing page in different languages

lang="pt-br, en-us"

Comment: it is not very good idea to have the same page with multiple languages on it (unless it is dictionary), probably you want different pages, also you can set lang attribute on tags to indicate parts of the page with different language

Comment: That is not really the purpose of that "The attribute contains a single "language tag" in the format defined" ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

Comment: That said, nothing prevents you from having many landing pages with different languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple languages on that page, you first define the main language of the page on the `html` element (`<html lang="en-US">`)
And for the elements that have a different language from the page, you add a `lang` attribute:

```
<section lang="pt-BR"> ... </section>
```

But it would still show all languages on the page. The `lang` attribute is just for SEO and accessibility/screenreaders. It won't hide languages.